Old Sci Fi movie about alien police officer/bounty hunter who crash lands on earth

It may have been a black and white movie
I'm guessing that it was made in the late 60's 70's
The alien policeman was transporting a fugitive who escaped when his ship crashed on earth.
The twist-- you were led to believe the fugitive was the 'good guy' and the policeman was the 'bad guy'
I think both aliens died 
I think the fugitive could shapeshift to look like a human
The police officer's ability to shapeshift and talk was damaged during the crash, hence everyone thought he was just an scary alien out to kill humans.

I watched this after school many years ago.

Was this film in English? If so, do you remember if it was American, British, or something else? You say you watched it "after school many years ago." Can you tell us approximately when that was? 2000? 1986? and maybe where? (It might jog someone else's memory.)

Yes, it was in english and I believe it was an American movie.  I saw it while in the US Midwest, sometime around 1982.
